# How do I access more sizes of TeX Gyre Schola in Plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

I am using the following line of (Xe)TeX code to include the TeX Gyre Schola font:

```
\input cs-schola
```

It works well with the \bf, \it, etc. commands but none of \ninerm, \small and \footnotesize are defined. How can I access other font sizes? Should I define the fonts myself?

Comment: Did you look at the [`font-change-xetex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/font-change-xetex?lang=en) package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `cs-schola` file does `\input ff-mac` and `\input csfontsm` and this macro-file defines `\resizefont` macro, you can simply use `\resizefont`. The syntax is `\resizefont\fontswitch` where `\fontswitch` is a font selector defined by `\font` primitive. The `\fontswitch` is (locally) changed when `\resizefont` is applied by following rule:

The font is kept the same. Its size is changed due to the actual value of the `\sizespec` macro. This macro can include `at dimen` or `scaled number`.

Example. When `\input cs-schola` is done, then `\tenrm` is font selector for roman variant of the Schola family. You can do:

```
\input cs-schola

{\def\sizespec{at15pt}  % size declaration
 \resizefont\tenrm      % \resizefont application
 \tenrm Text is printed at 15 pt.  % re-sized \tenrm is used.
}
now, the text is at 10pt. % because \resizefont works locally.

\bye
```

More information about `\resizefont` is in the file `csfontsm.tex`.

Comment: Great thank you, I think there is also a resizeall macro